# How to use execvp() & fork()

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, exec

I am new to process control, I would like to use my program code.c to show message when the child process runs and after the message get printed execute a command. In my test case, I am running my program as $code.exe pwd, but later on I plan to incorporate more lengthy commands like ls -a. My problem is that ehn I run my program I do not get the message from the child and I get the execution of 2 pwd commands. Could someone help me understand this behavior a bit better?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int execute (char *newargv[]);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    
    char * newargv[argc];
    newargv[0] = argv[1];
    newargv[1] = NULL;
    
    printf("[0] -> %s\n",newargv[0]);
    execute(newargv);
    
    return 0;
    }


int execute(char*newargv[])    {
    long lForkPid;
    long lMyVal = 10;


    // Call to fork():
   
    lForkPid = fork();
    
    execvp(newargv[0],newargv);
    // Both the parent and child continue here
    switch(lForkPid)
    {
        case -1: //Error ocurred
            return -1;
        
            break;
        
        case 0: // Child Proceess
           printf("Child process will use: %s", newargv[0]);  // Message that displays command
           break;

        default:// Parent Process:
       break; 
        }

    lMyVal +=5;
    
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You call `execvp` in both child and parent with the same parameters. Move it to your `switch` statement

Comment: That helped a lot, Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the comment  `// Both the parent and child continue here`.  Neither continue after `execvp` unless `execvp` fails.